# Constant template arguments for functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have the defined the following types:

```
template <typename TType>
struct symbol{};

template <typename TAtom, unsigned IDim>
struct tensor_type {};

template <unsigned IDim>
using real = tensor_type<double, IDim>;

template <unsigned IDim>
using index = tensor_type<int, IDim>;
```

I now want to call functions with instances of the type symbol like this:

```
template <template<typename TType, unsigned IDim> typename TTemplate, typename TType, unsigned IDim>
void f(symbol<TTemplate<TType, IDim>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "higher dimension" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    symbol<real<0>>* p1 =  new symbol<real<0>>();
    symbol<index<0>>* p2 =  new symbol<index<0>>();
    symbol<real<1>>* p3 =  new symbol<real<1>>();
    symbol<index<5>>* p4 =  new symbol<index<5>>();

    f(p1); //dimension 0
    f(p2); //dimension 0
    f(p3); //higher dimension
    f(p4); //higher dimension
}
```

This works fine and well. But now I want to differ between symbols of the dimension 0 and all the other dimensions, but I do not know how to properly declare an overloaded function properly with the templates to achive this.

I have tried the following:

```
template <typename TType>
void f(symbol<TType<0>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```

with `error: ‘TType’ is not a template` during compilation and

```
template <template<typename TType> typename TTemplate, typename TType>
void f(symbol<TTemplate<TType>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```

with `error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)`.

I cannot include the code for both dimensions in one function because in the actual implementation types with dimension 0 have different attributes than the one with higher dimensions, so even if I use a case distinction in the function the compiler complains that some passed arguments do not have the needed attribute.

One possiblity is to declare a function for every possible type for dimension 0 like this

```
void f(symbol<real<0>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```

but since I have multiple types in the actual implementation and all the functions would look exactly the same (besides the signature) I wanted to avoid redundant code.

Is there some way to achive this more elegant?

Comment: As a sidenote: There seems to be no reason for all the pointers. Just write e.g. `parameter_symbol<real<0>>* p1;` and take arguments by-reference. It will make the code much less error-prone.

Comment: Isn’t there just a template argument missing for your overload: `template <template <typename, int> class TTemplate, typename TType> void f(parameter_symbol<TTemplate<TType, 0>>* sym)`. Otherwise, the easiest approach is to use the same function with an  `if constexpre (IDim == 0) { … } else { … }`.

Comment: Where is the definition for `parameter_symbol`?

Comment: @rturrado Corrected this.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes I was missing one template argument. Since as mentioned depending on the dimension the objects have different  attributes, ```if constexpre (IDim == 0) { … } else { … }.``` will give me an error that I am accessing an attribute that is not there.

Comment: It shouldn’t: the code within the inactive `if constexpr` branch can have code which can’t be instantiated. It just needs to be syntactically correct and work in case it is the active branch.

Answer (score 2):

In your shown example, there is only one relevant class template: `tensor_type`

The others declared with `using` are just aliases for this one. They do not define new class templates or types.

So with that it is enough to simply specify that template in the overload:

```
template <typename T>
void f(parameter_symbol<tensor_type<T, 0>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```

---

If you have multiple templates, some of which you haven't shown, then

```
template <template<typename, unsigned> typename TTemplate, typename T>
void f(parameter_symbol<TTemplate<T, 0>>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```

will work. Note that the kinds of template parameter in the template template parameter `template<typename, unsigned> typename TTemplate` must match the class template that you are going to use as argument. (As one exception, you can also replace `unsigned` with `auto`.)

If you have multiple templates with different kinds of template parameters, then you need define such overloads for all cases.
If the dimension is not always in the same position in the parameter list, then this approach doesn't work.

---

It would be simpler to have the relevant classes provide a `constexpr` static member variable `idim` which indicates the dimension, or a `constexpr` static function returning it. Or alternatively a specialized free variable template or function template.

Then you can have a function overload taking any type and constrain it through SFINAE or if you can use C++20, a `requires` class:

```
template <typename T>
requires(T::idim == 0)
void f(parameter_symbol<T>* sym) {
    std::cout << "dimension 0" << std::endl;
}
```